# I'd like to use the Adafruit nrf52 feather with a rotary encoder. I'd like to see a working example of sending media and other control keys

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, adafruit, nrf52

I'd like to use the Adafruit nrf52 feather to build a bluetooth keyboard emulator.  I'd like to see a working example of sending media and other control keys.

Answer (score 0):

The Nordic SDK has HID examples, but you will have to do some work to implement your own HID report/descriptors stuff. The nRF52 also has HW support for a single quadrature rotary encoder, also in the SDK.

http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.sdk/keydef/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.2.0/index.html?cp=4_0_1

http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.nrf52832.ps.v1.1/qdec.html?cp=2_1_0_35#concept_isq_pwd_4r